# Thinkpad with Optimus in low graphics mode after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I upgraded my TP W520 with Optimus from 13.10 to 14.04
Under 13.10 optimus worked will. Setup with the following: http://www.unixreich.com/blog/2013/linux-nvidia-optimus-on-thinkpad-w520w530-with-external-monitor-finally-solved/

Before the upgrade I removed xorg-edgers ppa with `ppa-purge`

After the upgrade I restated and I only can enter the low graphics mode.

I already tired to add xorg-edgers again and also to purge / reinstall bumblebee and nvidia but without success.

I don't know whats wrong...

**Update:**

When I open the console and use: `sudo pkill -9 Xorg` and then: `startx`

I get into unity.

My Xorg.0.log:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     5.764]
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[     5.764] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     5.764] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     5.764] Current Operating System: Linux steve-ThinkPad-W520 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
[     5.764] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=50134307-3b47-46ea-babf-a6afc5482a7e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     5.764] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:36:29PM
[     5.764] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[     5.764] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[     5.764]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     5.764] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     5.765] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu May  1 17:14:36 2014
[     5.767] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     5.767] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     5.771] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     5.771] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     5.771] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     5.771] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     5.771] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[     5.771] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     5.771] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     5.771] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     5.772] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     5.772]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.772] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.772]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.772] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.772]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.772] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     5.772]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.772] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     5.772]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.772] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[     5.772] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     5.772] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     5.772] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f0af3543d60
[     5.772] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     5.772]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     5.772]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[     5.772]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[     5.772]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     5.772] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     5.774] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0126:17aa:21d1 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf2400000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64
[     5.774] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0dda:17aa:21d1 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf0000000/33554432, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/67108864, I/O @ 0x00005000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension Present
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[     5.775] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[     5.775] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[     5.775] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     5.775] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[     5.775] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     5.780] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     5.796] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.796]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.796]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[     5.796] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     5.796] Loading extension GLX
[     5.796] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[     5.796] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[     5.796] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[     5.796] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[     5.796] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[     5.796] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     5.796] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     5.798] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     5.803] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.803]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.911
[     5.803]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.803]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     5.803] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.803] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     5.804] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.804]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[     5.804]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.804]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     5.804] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     5.804] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     5.805] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.805]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[     5.805]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.805]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     5.805] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     5.805] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     5.807] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.807]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[     5.807]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.807]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     5.807] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
        i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
        915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
        Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
        GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[     5.807] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-5000
[     5.807] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100
[     5.807] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200
[     5.807] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     5.807] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     5.807] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     5.807] (++) using VT number 7

[     5.808] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.911+git20140429.2fd1a05a-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty (Rico Tzschichholz <ricotz@ubuntu.com>)
[     5.809] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     5.810] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     5.810] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     5.810] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     5.810] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     5.810] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.810]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[     5.810]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     5.810] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     5.811] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
[     5.811] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx
[     5.811] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     5.811] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.811] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.811] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.811] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[     5.811] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[     5.811] (**) intel(0): "Tear free" disabled
[     5.811] (**) intel(0): Forcing per-crtc-pixmaps? no
[     5.811] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 64x64 for hardware cursors
[     5.811] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[     5.811] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface acpi_video0 (type 'firmware') for output LVDS1
[     5.811] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[     5.811] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[     5.811] (--) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1920x1080 on pipe 0
[     5.811] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[     5.811] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     5.811] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     5.811] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     5.812] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.812] (II) Unloading modesetting
[     5.812] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     5.812] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     5.812] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     5.812] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[     5.812] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     5.812] (II) Unloading vesa
[     5.812] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     5.817] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Sandybridge (gen6, gt2) backend
[     5.817] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[     5.817] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     5.817] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[     5.818] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[     5.818] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[     5.818] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     5.818] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[     5.818] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[     5.818] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
[     5.818] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
[     5.819] (--) RandR disabled
[     5.823] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[     5.854] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[     5.854] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[     5.858] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[     5.868] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[     5.877] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     5.880] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[     5.880] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.880] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     5.880] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     5.881] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.881]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.8.2
[     5.881]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     5.881]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[     5.881] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     5.881] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     5.882] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[     5.882] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     5.882] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     5.882] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.882] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[     5.882] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     5.882] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.882] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.882] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.884] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-808BBA3D4C227BDB44C370226C34E44C5D69A4A9.xkm
[     5.885] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[     5.885] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.885] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[     5.885] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     5.885] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[     5.885] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[     5.885] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[     5.885] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.885] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event5"
[     5.885] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     5.885] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.885] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.885] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.886] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[     5.886] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.886] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[     5.886] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     5.886] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[     5.886] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[     5.886] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[     5.886] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.886] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0a/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8/event6"
[     5.886] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[     5.886] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.886] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.886] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.886] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[     5.886] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.886] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.887] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[     5.887] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.887] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[     5.887] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[     5.887] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[     5.887] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[     5.887] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[     5.887] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.887] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[     5.887] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[     5.887] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.887] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.887] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.887] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     5.887] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     5.888] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated Camera (/dev/input/event12)
[     5.888] (**) Integrated Camera: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.888] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Integrated Camera'
[     5.888] (**) Integrated Camera: always reports core events
[     5.888] (**) evdev: Integrated Camera: Device: "/dev/input/event12"
[     5.888] (--) evdev: Integrated Camera: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0xb217
[     5.888] (--) evdev: Integrated Camera: Found keys
[     5.888] (II) evdev: Integrated Camera: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.888] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input14/event12"
[     5.888] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Integrated Camera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[     5.888] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.888] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.888] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.888] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[     5.888] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.888] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.889] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone (/dev/input/event8)
[     5.889] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.889] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.889] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event7)
[     5.889] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.889] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.889] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[     5.889] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.889] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.889] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[     5.889] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.889] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     5.889] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     5.889] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[     5.889] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[     5.889] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[     5.889] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.889] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[     5.889] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[     5.889] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.889] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.889] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.890] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event11)
[     5.890] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[     5.890] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     5.890] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     5.890] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     5.890] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     5.892] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.892]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.7.4
[     5.892]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     5.892]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[     5.892] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[     5.892] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     5.892] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event11"
[     5.936] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: ignoring touch events for semi-multitouch device
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5888 (res 75)
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4820 (res 105)
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[     5.936] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[     5.936] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     5.952] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event11"
[     5.952] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[     5.952] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     5.952] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[     5.952] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.036
[     5.952] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     5.952] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     5.952] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     5.952] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     5.952] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[     5.952] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     5.952] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[     5.953] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad Extra Buttons (/dev/input/event4)
[     5.953] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.953] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons'
[     5.953] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: always reports core events
[     5.953] (**) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[     5.953] (--) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Vendor 0x17aa Product 0x5054
[     5.953] (--) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Found keys
[     5.953] (II) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.953] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input6/event4"
[     5.953] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ThinkPad Extra Buttons" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[     5.953] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.953] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.953] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.954] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad HDAPS joystick emulation (/dev/input/event13)
[     5.954] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.954] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.954] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad HDAPS joystick emulation (/dev/input/js0)
[     5.954] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.954] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.954] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer data (/dev/input/event14)
[     5.954] (**) ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer data: Ignoring device from InputClass "ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer blacklist"
[     5.954] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer data (/dev/input/js1)
[     5.954] (**) ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer data: Ignoring device from InputClass "ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer blacklist"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: Integrated Camera: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.120] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[     6.120] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[     6.141] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out the following line in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
display-setup-script=/sbin/hybrid-power
```

Now I can successfully boot into unity

Answer (score 0):

14.04 has several problems with hybrid graphics cards, specially the ones that came with 2nd gen intel processors and hd graphics with AMD/NVidia discrete GPUs,

The best possible solution is just use the open source driver or install the intel driver from the intel download center,
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/
install the driver from here , 
if you are not into high end gaming in linux and that is more than sufficient :)